Trying to make a WiFi Range Extender using Skyworks
I'm trying to design a WiFi range extender that can help increase the range of RF signals from an Intel M.2 8265NGW module. Similar to how these amplifiers from sunhans and others do. I initially tried getting eval kits from Skyworks, SKY65900-11-EVB, SE2576L-EK1, SE2623L-EK1, SKY66292. But to my disappointment none of them are able to amplify the signal effectively. (I don't think they are amplifying at all). Later, with the help of others, I found out that I was not allowing for the Rx signals coming from the antenna (as the PA was sitting in the path).
After some digging, I am coming to the conclusion that the system has to look like the block diagram below. It needs two set of switches, to switch between TX and RX signals, as WiFi is TDD. However, I don't know how do I manage the control signals for each switch (ctrl1,2,3,4). Normally, in other radio boards that I have seen, there's a WiFi SoC that handles these switches. But how do I supply it in this case, where there's no control signals from the WiFi module. Moreover, how do these range extenders handle it. They don't use any control signals either. I feel like I'm missing something here. If anyone has any idea on this?

On another note: Initially, I was directly giving the output of the Intel 8265 to the Skyworks eval boards. But later found out that the boards cannot handle more than 0dB of input. So, I started putting attenuators and testing. I tried with different off-the shelf attenuators, and would see the gain go up by 30dB or so. I still don't know how other range extenders do it, I don't see attenuators in their path. They are directly able to take the output of the Intel 8265 boards and amplify, without the need of any attenuation.
